# How to fix abntex2 first page in the bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, page-numbering, fancyhdr, bibliographystyle

It seems that the first page in the bibliography when using the abntex2 package puts the page number in the upper right side of the page, how do I correct this so that the page numbering of only the first page goes to the bottom of the page? I have tryied to force this using

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
```

and

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

Here is a minimum (not)working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english,sumario=tradicional]{abntex2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makepagestyle{estilo_pretextual} %
\makeevenhead{estilo_pretextual}{}{}{\ABNTEXfontereduzida \textbf \thepage}
\makeoddhead{estilo_pretextual}{}{}{\ABNTEXfontereduzida \textbf \thepage}

\renewcommand{\pretextual}{
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{estilo_pretextual}
\pagestyle{estilo_pretextual}
\aliaspagestyle{cleared}{empty}
\aliaspagestyle{part}{estilo_pretextual}
 }

\let\oldtextual\textual        
\renewcommand{\textual}{%
\oldtextual%
\pagenumbering{arabic} % 
 }

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\cite{QvonNeu,StanfEP,Dirac,arnold,Bell,Bib1,SpTh,vonNeu,Luders,Pauli,TLQM,Hepp1,ArakiYanase, Fewst,Bib4,Hardy,BratRob2}


\pagestyle{plain}
    \newpage

\pagestyle{plain}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{ref} % Replace "ref" with the name of your bibliography file

\pagestyle{plain}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

where I used the following minimal bibliography example in a file called "ref.bib":

```
@article{ArakiYanase,
title={Measurement of Quantum Mechanical Operators},
author={H. Araki and M. M. Yanase},
journal={Physical Review},
volume={120 (2)},
pages={622–626},
year={1960}
}
@book{arnold,
title={Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics },
author={V. I. Arnol'd},
series={Graduate Texts in Mathematics},
volume={60},
edition={2},
year={1989},
publisher={Springer}
}
@article{Bell,
title={On Wave Packet Reduction in the \text{C}oleman–\text{H}epp Model},
author={J. S. Bell},
journal={Helv. Phys. Acta},
volume={48},
publisher={Birkhäuser},
address={Basel},
year={1975}
}
@book{TLQM,
title={The Logic of Quantum Mechanics},
author={E.G. Beltrametti and G. Cassinelli},
series={ENCYCLOPEDIA OF MATHEMATICS and Its Applications},
year={1981},
address = {Genoa},
publisher={Addison-Wesley}
}
@book{BratRob1,
title={Operator algebras and quantum statistical mechanics. 1},
subtitle={$C^{*}-$ and $W^{*}-$algebras, symmetry groups, decomposition of states},
author={O. Bratteli and D.W. Robinson},
address = {New York},
year={1987},
series={Texts and Monographs in Physics},
edition={2},
publisher={Springer-Verlag}
}
@book{BratRob2,
title={Operator algebras and quantum statistical mechanics. 2},
subtitle={Equilibrium states. Models in quantum statistical
mechanics},
author={O. Bratteli and D.W. Robinson},
address = {Berlin},
year={1997},
series={Texts and Monographs in Physics},
edition={2},
publisher={Springer-Verlag}
}
@book{Dirac,
title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
author={P. A. M. Dirac},
edition={4},
year={1930},
address = {Oxford},
series={The International Series of Monographs on Physics},
publisher={Clarendon Press}
}
@inproceedings{Fewst,
title={A generally covariant measurement scheme for quantum field theory in curved spacetimes},
author={C. J. Fewster},
booktitle={Progress and Visions in Quantum Theory in View of Gravity},
subtitle={: Bridging Foundations of Physics and Mathematics},
editor={F. Finster and D. Giulini  and J. Kleiner and J. Tolksdorf },
publisher={Birkhäuser},
address={Cham},
year={2020}
}
@article{Hardy,
title={Quantum mechanics, local realistic theories, and \text{L}orentz-invariant realistic theories},
author={L. Hardy},
journal={Physical Review Letters},
volume={68 (20)},
pages={2981–2984},
year={1992}
}
@article{Hepp1,
title={Quantum Theory of Measurement and
Macroscopic Observables},
author={K. Hepp},
volume={45},
pages={237},
year={1972},
address={Basel},
journal={Helv. Phys. Acta},
publisher={Birkhäuser Verlag}
}
@article{Luders,
title={Über die Zustandsänderung durch den Meßprozeß},
author={G. Lüders},
volume={8},
pages={322-328},
year={1951},
address={Leipzig},
journal={Ann. Phys.},
publisher={J.A. Barth Verlag}
}
@book{SpTh,
title={Spectral Theory and Quantum Mechanics},
subtitle={Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Theories, Symmetries and Introduction to the Algebraic Formulation},
edition={2},
author={V. Moretti},
series={UNITEXT - La Matematica per il 3+2},
volume={110},
year={2017},
publisher={Springer}
}
@misc{StanfEP,
author = {Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy},
title = {Quantum Mechanics},
year = {2020},
note ={available in \url{https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm/}, acessed in 24/03/2023}
}
@book{Pauli,
title={General Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
author={W. Pauli},
edition={2},
year={1958},
address = {Berlin},
publisher={Springer-Verlag}
}
@book{Bib1,
title={Methods of modern mathematical physics},
volume={I},
subtitle={Functional analysis},
author={M. Reed and B. Simon},
edition={2},
publisher={Academic Press, Inc.},
address={New York},
year={1980}
}
@book{Bib4,
title={Methods of modern mathematical physics},
volume={IV},
subtitle={Analysis of Operators},
author={M. Reed and B. Simon},
edition={2},
publisher={Academic Press, Inc. },
address={New York},
year={1970}
}
@article{QvonNeu,
title={Von Neumann's contributions to quantum theory},
author={Léon van Hove},
volume={64},
number={3.P2},
pages={95-99},
year={1958},
journal={Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.},
publisher={American Mathematical Society}
}
@book{vonNeu,
title={Mathematische Grundlagen der Quantenmechanik},
author={J. von Neumann},
address = {Berlin},
year={1932},
publisher={Springer-Verlag}
}
```

Comment: But ABNT requires the page number on top or not? Are you going to change the ABNT rule?

Comment: Well, consulting some tens of other master's dissertations, that does not seem to be a major offense if it is only in the first page of the bibliography. Also, no one that is mentally sane is able to abide by all ABNT rules, there are literally self contadicting instructions in that thing, and my university (USP) doesn't even follow the ABNT standard for the catalographic card (fixa catalográfica).

Comment: So yes! I am trying to change the enforced abnt2 standard only for the first page of the bibliography, even if it goes against ABNT itself.